# css media query question

Tags: customization, css, child-theme

I guess this is a novice question but here it is.

I have been editing a child theme CSS and trying to change this specific code

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
    #carousel-hestia-generic span.sub-title {
        font-size: 24px; 
    }
```

Which I see from the inspect in Chrome. When I add it to my style.css in my child theme and make the font size let's say 36px, it doesn't change. 
Actually, Chrome shows a strikethrough...

**the element I want to change**
https://snag.gy/izc10u.jpg

**the CSS file in my child theme**
https://snag.gy/GVfDs9.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #carousel-hestia-generic span.sub-title {
        font-size: 24px; 
    }
}
```

Notice how **@media** has a block `{}` which contains the CSS selector you want to work with.

Comment: thank you for your immediate help, but it doesn't actually work again... even with your code. Check this: https://snag.gy/afSFVq.jpg    and also this          https://snag.gy/HsGlfA.jpg

Comment: Just for testing use font-size: 40px !important; and check if there is any difference.

Comment: with the "!important it did work! thank you so much...